# How to Show Virtual Keyboard in El Capitan?

Tags: keyboard, macos, ui

I changed to El Capitan and I cannot find anymore the virtual keyboard about testing keyboard's keys visually. 
It is normally in the right hand corner under the keyboard switcher icon. 
I need the tool to review specific characters of OS X Keyboards, since I am typing many of them.

How can you have the virtual keyboard in OS X El Capitan?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard > Show Keyboard, Emoji & Symbol viewers in menu bar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why they added the word *Emoji* in El Capitan because it confused me.

Comment: I'd make grand sweeping comments about Apple becoming a *"lifestyle product for the type-with-your-thumbs generation"* & forgetting its old user-base… but someone would complain ;)

Answer (score -1):

in my case when i checked "show keyboard- and character bla bla" nothing happens what so ever. No onscreen-keyboard?? I also run El Capitan...

ah never mind, my mistake. It's Yosemite i do run, not El Capitan. but still there's no keyboard Viewer showing?

SOLUTION 4 SHOWING THE ONSCREEN-KEYBOARD:
**move mouse to upper part of the screen and right-click the language flag icon to actually show the onscreen-keyboard.**

Comment: Like it says in the original question:  “It is normally in the right hand corner under the keyboard switcher icon.”. Maybe you should just delete this to avoid confusion, since you didn’t really have the problem asked about.

Comment: Actually this answer helped me, it's more clear.